# what mean of calling command (param1, param2, ...)

Tags: javascript

I read an e-book and find this command, but I don't know it's purpose and when to using it. Example:

```
var x = (12, 34, 56)
```

x in this case is a number and it's value is 56. Thanks.

This is the full script I read from ebook 'Javascript for absolute Beginners':

```
var fridge = {
buttermilk: [1/3, "cup"],
kefir: [1 + 1/2, "cup"],
yogurt: [4, "cup"],
};
var dough = {
hardWhiteWholeWheatFlour: [2, "cup"],
sugar: [1/3, "cup"],
madagascarVanilla: [1, "tsp"],
orangeZest: [1, "tbs"],
soda: [1, "tsp"],
tartar: [1, "tsp"],
orangeJuice: [1/2, "cup"],
culturedMilk: [1/2, "cup"],
egg: [1],
cranberries: [2/3, "cup"]
};
dough.culturedMilk[0] = fridge.buttermilk[0] >= 1/2 ? (fridge.buttermilk[0] -= 1/2, 1/2) :
fridge.kefir[0] >= 9/16 ? (fridge.kefir[0] -= 9/16, 9/16) :
fridge.yogurt[0] >= 10/16 ? (fridge.yogurt[0] -= 10/16, 10/16) :
alert("No cranberry bread for you!");
dough.culturedMilk;
// [0.5625, "cup"]
fridge.kefir;
// [0.9375, "cup"]
```

Comment: And the expression in question in the script is `(fridge.buttermilk[0] -= 1/2, 1/2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already know  what it means... evaluated each operand and return the result of the last.

In the case of `(fridge.buttermilk[0] -= 1/2, 1/2)`, the expression itself is part of the conditional operator:

```
fridge.buttermilk[0] >= 1/2 ? (fridge.buttermilk[0] -= 1/2, 1/2) : ...
```

In this case, the comma operator is used to introduce side effects. If `fridge.buttermilk[0] >= 1/2` is true, then `1/2` should be assigned to `dough.culturedMilk[0]`. But at the same time, `fridge.buttermilk[0]` should be updated as well.

Normally you would use two expression statements, like

```
if(fridge.buttermilk[0] >= 1/2) {
    fridge.buttermilk[0] -= 1/2;
    dough.culturedMilk[0] = 1/2;
}
```

but since the author wants to use the conditional operator, the comma operator can be used to execute both expression in one expression. It updates the value of `fridge.buttermilk[0]` and returns `1/2`.

I'm not recommending doing this though, especially in this case, with nested conditional operators, a traditional `if-else` statement would be easier to read.

Comment: I understood this problem. This is too complex for beginner.

Answer (score 1):

If the condition 
        fridge.buttermilk[0] >= 1/2

is satisfied, then two things are happening. 
fridge.buttermilk[0] is reduced by 1/2
and dough.culturedMilk[0] is made equal to 1/2

Try this...

```
     a = 10
     b = a < 20 ? (a -= 3, 2) : (a += 3, 5)
```

and see the values of a and b

Answer (score 0):

For example this line:

```
(fridge.kefir[0] -= 9/16, 9/16)
```

as you see in the comment will decrease the kefir-s value with 9/16, 3/2 - 9/16 = 0,9375, and returns the 9/16 as the value for the culturedMilk.

(param1, param2 ...) evaluates the expressions and returns the last one. (Like in your example)